# Validate an array of objects with class-validator and Nest.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, nestjs, class-validator

I am using class-validator with NestJS and trying to validate an array of objects, with this layout:

```
[
    {gameId: 1, numbers: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]},
    {gameId: 2, numbers: [5, 6, 3, 5, 8]}
]
```

My resolver

```
createBet(@Args('createBetInput') createBetInput: CreateBetInput) {
    return this.betsService.create(createBetInput);
  }
```

My createBetInput DTO

```
import { InputType, Field, Int } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { IsArray, IsNumber } from 'class-validator';

@InputType()
export class CreateBetInput {
  @IsNumber()
  @Field(() => Int)
  gameId: number;

  @Field(() => [Int])
  @IsArray()
  numbers: number[];
}
```

I've tried some solutions but I haven't been successful, honestly, I have no idea how to do this.

How can I modify the DTO to get the necessary validation?

Comment: Dont forget ` @Type(()=>LineDto)` on the arrary field

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are options of `class-validator` mixed with `class-transformer` to validating nested objects, your Array also is a nested object, so you can validate that like this:

```
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsArray, ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';

class ItemsOfBet {
  @IsArray()
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => CreateBetInput)
  items: CreateBetInput[];
}
```

Comment: It should be emphasized that the `@Type` line is important else the validation wont take place

Comment: cant this be done without creating a new type for hosting array, what if i just wanted to use CreateBetInput[] at controller level?

Comment: @DeekshithAnand as we get body data from the controller's parameters and they usually are in JSON objects with the format of `{...data}` and best practices say not to use array formats for the top level of the body objects like `[...data]`  so this is a right pattern.